# If a Tempest cleric uses the Wrath of the Storm and Thunderbolt Strike features to push an attacker away, can the attacker complete its multiattack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, reactions, multiattack

The Tempest Domain cleric's Thunderbolt Strike feature (PHB, p. 62) says:

> At 6th level, when you deal lightning damage to a Large or smaller creature, you can also push it up to 10 feet away from you.

I envision the Thunderbolt Strike as throwing the target creature away from it, not gently pushing it away. I mean, lightning is an instantaneous thing, and 10 feet is more than just losing your balance.

The Thunderbolt Strike feature of a Tempest cleric leaves me with many questions. For instance, if a monster is able to make a multiattack consisting of 2 claw attacks and then a bite, and it hits me with its first attack, I can use Wrath of Storm as a reaction to deal lightning damage to it, and thereby blast the creature back 10 feet using Thunderbolt Strike.

If the monster does not have 10 feet of movement left after being pushed, does it lose its other 2 attacks against me (if no other targets are in range of it)? Or does it get to make all 3 attacks before it is blasted away from me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you use Wrath of the Storm with Thunderbolt Strike, the creature that attacked you is pushed back immediately. From the section on reactions:

> If the reaction interrupts
>   another creature’s turn, that creature can continue its
>   turn right after the reaction.

The creature doesn't get to finish its turn, *then* get hit by your reaction - your reaction happens straight away, interrupting their turn. So if you use Wrath of the Storm + Thunderbolt Strike on the 1st attack of a Multiattack, the creature will be pushed back 10 feet.

Then, if it has movement remaining, it can move up to you and finish its Multiattack sequence. If it does not have enough movement to get back within reach of you, it will have to either end its turn without completing its Multiattack, or take the other attack(s) on a creature that is within its reach.

Comment: +1 for including the point of movement, since if a creature uses all of its movement to get to you and multiattack, the reaction disrupts, but if there is spare movement the creature can re-engage.