# Can you cast Hellish Rebuke as a reaction to damage that reduces you to zero hit points?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, reactions, unconscious

Can one use a *hellish rebuke* as a reaction after taking damage that would  knock one unconscious?

A friend and I fought during one game and I hit him, so he would have lost,
but used his reaction to finish me, too. (It was awesome :D)

Comment: The Tempest Domain cleric has a similar "reaction equals damage" ability (Wrath of the Storm) that looks related to this question. I didn't find a question on that, but there is one that is somewhat related: [If a Tempest cleric uses the Wrath of the Storm and Thunderbolt Strike features to push an attacker away, can the attacker complete its multiattack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70100/if-a-tempest-cleric-uses-the-wrath-of-the-storm-and-thunderbolt-strike-features)

Comment: How many times did you hit him?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I just asked the question about WotS here: [How does the reaction timing work for Wrath of the Storm? Can it potentially prevent the damage from the triggering attack?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77552/28034)

Answer (score 55):

Unfortunately, as awesome as this sounds, by the rules, it doesn't work. *Hellish Rebuke* is a reaction that you take

> in response to being damaged

Not "in response to being hit", or "in response to being attacked". You actually have to take damage to use it.

> Whenever a creature takes damage, that damage is
>   subtracted from its hit points.

You haven't taken the damage until you've subtracted it from your hit points. If that puts you on 0 hit points, then

> you either die outright or
>   fall unconscious

At which point, you are incapacitated and can't use reactions.

Comment: Thank you, too.
This was my first instinct, too and I would decide to play it like that if I would have been the DM, but I am grateful for the fun experience of a double ko. ^^

Comment: @wOlF It's possible your DM knew it would work like this but decided it was awesome enough that it was worth allowing anyway!

Comment: "You haven't taken the damage until you've subtracted it from your hit points" The RAW doesn't actually *say* that though. Actually it seems like that interpretation is completely ruled out. Whenever a creature takes damage, that damage is subtracted from its hit points, but, you haven't taken damage until you subtract the hit points? That sounds like 'we won't give you a job without experience, but you can't get experience without a job'-type thinking. Altering HP and reactions are both *consequences* to taking damage.

Comment: tl;dr: "Whenever a creature takes damage, that damage is subtracted from its hit points, but, you haven't taken the damage until you've subtracted it from your hit points." Say wha-?? ;) :D

Comment: @Shane Taking damage *is* subtracting it from your hit points. You can't get a job without, yanno, getting a job.

Comment: That's fair. I'm just pointing out for anyone that comes along later that (at least from the passages you've quoted) this answer isn't RAW. The OP didn't use the RAW tag and wasn't asking for RAW, and it appears that at a rate of nearly 2-1 people agree with your interpretation of RAI, so that's legit. Grammatically, that sentence structure doesn't describe an identity relationship. "Whenever you next go to the store, pick up some milk" - "Whenever you stub your toe, it hurts"

Comment: @Shane Here's a better argument: as explained in the DMG, a reaction always occurs *after* its trigger unless stated otherwise. The trigger here is taking damage, so by the time you can take the reaction you'll have suffered all of the consequences of that damage, including potentially being knocked unconscious. By that same token, if you were affected by Hypnotic Pattern and took damage, you'd be able to use Hellish Rebuke because one of the consequences of taking damage is Hypnotic Pattern ending.

Comment: By the same logic then (since it uses the similar phrasing of "take damage") you can't use Absorb Elements to reduce damage that takes you to 0 HP.
Or actually, without really stretching the argument, Absorb Element's resistance would not apply to the triggering instance of damage, since you're arguing that the spell effect takes place /after/ the triggering damage

Comment: Absorb Elements also state "The spell captures some of the incoming energy, _lessening its effect on you_ and storing it for your next melee attack.", which implies it reduces the damage taken. The Shield spell get's a bit paradox-y as well. The reaction trigger is being hit, but the spell itself adds AC that can prevent you from being hit, which was the trigger in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

The rules are (my emphasis):

Hit Points (PHB p.196)

> Whenever a creature takes damage, *that damage is
>   subtracted from its hit points*. *The loss of hit points has
>   no effect on a creature’s capabilities* until the creature
>   drops to 0 hit points.

Unconsciousness (PHB p.197)

> If damage reduces you to 0 hit points and fails to kill you, you fall unconscious.

Hellish Rebuke (PHB p.250)

> **Casting Time**: *1 reaction*, which you take *in response
>   to being damaged* by a creature within 60 feet of you
>   that you can see

Reaction (PHB p.190)

> A reaction
>   is an *instant* response to a trigger of some kind, which
>   can occur on your turn or on someone else’s.

There are two possible sequences here:

- damage (trigger) -> reaction (Hellish Rebuke) -> subtracted from hit points -> unconscious
- (damage -> subtracted from hit points -> unconscious [all as a single event]) (trigger) -> can't react because unconscious

For mine, a reaction is an **instant** response to the trigger, and instant means instant; it interrupts the normal sequence of subtracting damage from hp and falling unconscious (or dying) so the first option is the one I think works.

Notwithstanding, awesome should **always** beat the rules.

Comment: There's no call for arguing in the comments. There are two opposite answers: vote according to which you think is correct.