# How does the reaction timing work for Wrath of the Storm? Can it potentially prevent the damage from the triggering attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, cleric, reactions

With attacks of opportunity, the PHB is pretty clear that your reaction occurs as an interruption to your opponent's move, just before they move beyond your reach, then they resume their turn. Fair enough.

However, there are some abilities that happen during an opponent's attack - for example, the Shield spell, and a Tempest cleric's Wrath of the Storm ability. These both say they happen when you're "hit" by an attack - but the Shield spell raises your AC, so I assume that occurs before rolling damage, and makes it possible for you to be retroactively *not* hit by the attack. Is the same true for Wrath - that your reaction might KO your opponent, and you wouldn't have to worry about taking damage?

(I was planning to include Hellish Rebuke in this question but I see it specifically refers to "being damaged", so I assume that means it happens on your opponent's turn but definitely after getting hit, meaning you can only cast it if you're still conscious.)

Comment: Related: [Can you cast Hellish Rebuke as a reaction to damage that reduces you to zero hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77082/can-you-cast-hellish-rebuke-as-a-reaction-to-damage-that-reduces-you-to-zero-hit)

Comment: Related: [Do reactions interrupt their triggers or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/do-reactions-interrupt-their-triggers-or-not)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, reactions interrupt whatever action they are reacting to, but only once that action has been resolved:

> Reactions
>
> Certain   special abilities,  spells, and situations  allow you   to  take    a   special action  called  a   reaction.   **A reaction    is  an  instant response    to  a   trigger of  some kind,  which   can occur   on  your    turn    or  on  someone else’s.**   The opportunity attack, described   later   in  this chapter,   is  the most    common  type    of  reaction.
>   When  you take    a   reaction,   you can’t   take    another one until   the start   of  your    next    turn.   **If    the reaction    interrupts  another creature’s  turn,   that    creature    can continue    its turn    right   after   the reaction.**

In the case of **Wrath of the Storm** it happens when you choose to react to this:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see hits you with an
>   attack

This triggers your reaction, and the enemy's attack has not yet been resolved.  Since the trigger happens before the damage (on the hit), it immediately interrupts the enemy's turn, including the damage resolution of the attack.  This is in line with how reactions are described above.  Thematically, think of it as the cleric exploding with electricity as an immediate response to being struck regardless of the damage the cleric takes in the process.

*Note that, even if this kills the enemy, **the damage from the hit that triggered wrath of the storm is still calculated.***

The spell *Shield* is a reaction you take when you are hit by an attack. It has additional special properties in the spell description:

> An invisible barrier of magical force appears and protects you. Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus to AC, *including against the triggering attack*, and you take no damage from magic missile.

So in this case, it is a specific exception to the rule that happens as a reaction to an attack that hits you, and it retroactively increases your AC against the triggering attack so that if the attack originally hit you, it might now miss.

Comment: What if the damage would have killed the Tempest Cleric:?  Trigger still good before damage?  *This triggers your reaction, and the enemy's attack has not yet been resolved. Since the trigger happens before the damage (on the hit), it immediately interrupts the enemy's turn, including the damage resolution of the attack*   While I like your ruling, I can see how a DM would consider the successful attack and the damage not to be separate operations.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm quite late on this response but I would rule that in this scenario, both damages are triggered regardless of the outcome of possible deaths/incapacitations.  The attack hits, the cleric explodes with lightning doing damage to the attacker, attacker's damage kills (**incapacitates**) the cleric.  I like the thematic resolution/rule of cool here.

Comment: I had the up vote cast back then, and I still like the answer, and your take on the "what if."  *thumbs up*  . :)

Answer (score 8):

Wrath of Storm does not protect from the damage of the triggering attack.

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind

This means that a reaction is preceded by the trigger chronologically, as a general rule. In the case of WoS, no further specific rules are given, so the general rule stands and the hit (and thus the damage) still occurs. For Shield, such a reading would render the AC bonus useless against the trigger. The text, however, reads:

> +5 bonus to AC, including against the triggering attack

The specific rule here states that the spell has a retroactive effect on it's trigger. This is why it has this unique ability, one which Wrath of Storm would not.

You're also entirely right about Hellish Rebuke, the reference to damage makes it a nonissue.

Answer (score 7):

Specific beats general.

The general rule is that reactions happen ***after*** the trigger is completed.

> A reaction 
>   is an instant response to a trigger of some kind

The word "response" requires the thing being responded to to have happened first.

*Shield* is an exception as are attacks of opportunity as their specific rules make them happen before the trigger.

The Tempest cleric's wrath contains no such exception so you must still be conscious after the trigger.

It is worth noting that there are circumstances where you can be hit but take no damage: a creature with a negative strength bonus, immunity, grapple, shove etc. Some reaction triggers are when you are hit: these work even if you are not damaged, others are when you are damaged by an attack.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli: Actually, one closing note since I just realized something... The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=11) *explicitly* rules out what you suggest: "**Does a grapple or a shove trigger the Tempest cleric’s Wrath of the Storm or a Battle Master’s Riposte?** The answer to both questions is no. The grappling and shoving options (PH, 195) don’t result in a hit or a miss."

Comment: @V2Blast - LOL. Well there we go then. Official rulings trump arguments! Thanks V2!